# SCSS How to define dynamic styles

Tags: css, sass

The following is my current code which occurs compile error.

```
$color-1: #353a4b;
$color-2: #5563a9;
$color-3: #7184e7;
$color-4: #c788e6;
$color-5: #f76789;

@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .bg-color-#{$i} {
    background-color: $color-#{$i};
  }

  .fg-color-#{$i} {
    color: $color-#{$i};
  }
}
```

This gives me the following error

```
SassError: Undefined variable: "$color-".
```

I would like to define dynamic styles using sass @for.

```
.bg-color-1 {
  background-color: $color-1;
}
.bg-color-2 {
  background-color: $color-2;
}

...
```

Could anyone can help me, please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One proper solution would be to `map` the `variables` and then use an `@each` loop to access them. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/mdPLQJd).

```
$colors: (
  color-1: #353a4b,
  color-2: #5563a9, 
  color-3: #7184e7, 
  color-4: #c788e6,
  color-5: #f76789,
);

@each $color in $colors {
  $index: index($colors, $color);
  $color: nth($color, 2);
  
  .bg-color-#{$index} {
    background-color: $color;
  }
  
  .fg-color-#{$index} {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool. That's pretty fast!